# Dynamic pattern for matching incorrect characters in egrep

Tags: regex, bash

I have the next lines in files:

```
UserParameter=cassandra.status[*], curl -s "http://$1:$2/server-status?auto" | grep -e $3 | awk '{ print $$2 }'

UserParameter=ping.status[*],curl -s --retry 3 --max-time 3 'http://localhost:1111/engines?$1' | awk '/last_seen = / {split($$1, a, "/"); print a[2]}; END { if (!NR) print "NO_MATCHING_ENGINES" }' | tr "\n" "
```

and so on.

I want to display that line where comma after [*] is missed or there are any extra characters besides comma.

For example:

```
UserParameter=ping.status[*],,,curl -s --retry 3 --max-time 3 'http://localhost:1111/engines?$1' | awk '/last_seen = / {split($$1, a, "/"); print a[2]}; END { if (!NR) print "NO_MATCHING_ENGINES" }' | tr "\n" " 
UserParameter=ping.status[*] curl -s --retry 3 --max-time 3 'http://localhost:1111/engines?$1' | awk '/last_seen = / {split($$1, a, "/"); print a[2]}; END { if (!NR) print "NO_MATCHING_ENGINES" }' | tr "\n" " 
UserParameter=ping.status[*],;!curl -s --retry 3 --max-time 3 'http://localhost:1111/engines?$1' | awk '/last_seen = / {split($$1, a, "/"); print a[2]}; END { if (!NR) print "NO_MATCHING_ENGINES" }' | tr "\n" "
```

will be printed as long as there are extra characters and spaces besides single comma.

But:

```
UserParameter=ping.status[*],curl -s --retry 3 --max-time 3 'http://localhost:1111/engines?$1' | awk '/last_seen = / {split($$1, a, "/"); print a[2]}; END { if (!NR) print "NO_MATCHING_ENGINES" }' | tr "\n" "
```

will not be printed as long as there is single comma after [*].

I was trying to develop a pattern for egrep, but it doesn't fit for all cases where for example besides comma any other character which follows after [*]:

```
egrep (\[\*\].(|;|:|,|\.|))
```

I'll appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: what *are* the valid characters *after* `[*],`? Seems like "c" for "curl" is OK; is that it?

Comment: $ / and letters are allowed.

Comment: how about a space? (your first example: `...status[*], curl...`)

Comment: Spaces are allowed as well but only after the single comma, however if We have status[*] .... string should be printed as long as comma is missed. The same refers to $ / and letters. They are not allowed at once after [*] if a comma is missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -vE '\[\*\],[$/[:alpha:] ]' input
```

Do *not* print lines that match the pattern: `[*],` followed by any of: `$`, `/`, alphabetic character, or a `space`.